# Creating standalone windows app using python including excel import and different libraries

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, py2exe

I want to create a windows app and send that app to my colleagues for their use, using python. I already wrote a code which imports an excel file and manipulate it to give an output. I used pandas, numpy libraries for that. Is there a way to create a simple standalone windows app indepent of phyton code which imports this excel file and stores in itself, takes some inputs  then gives an output? If possible could you recommend me best matched gui libraries for that purpose?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use pyinstaller, or a similar tool.